# Show next job execution scheduled time

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I was wondering if Quartz.Net has a way to tell (or better write in the logs) on the next execution... I mean, I have got a job that runs at 10:00 AM and it's scheduled to run every two hours... is there a way I can write something as Next run on 12:00AM? or do I have to parse the cron expression, then add it to the current date?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So when a job finishes, you want to write into a log file the time it is scheduled to run next, is that right?

Comment: yes! that's... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what logger you are using, but this approach should work with any logger that you can create instances of. Create instance of logger and pass it to job via `JobDataMap` and then use it inside of job. `IJobExecutionContext.NextFireTimeUtc` will tell you next execution time which you can write to a logger

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NLog;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

namespace QuartzSampleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

            StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

            await scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .Build();
            job.JobDataMap["logger"] = logger; // add logger to job data map

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .Build();

            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

            await scheduler.Shutdown();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the application");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // simple log provider to get something to the console
    }

    public class HelloJob : IJob
    {
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Greetings from HelloJob!");

            var logger = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap["logger"] as ILogger;

            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Next job execution at " + context.NextFireTimeUtc);
        }
    }
}
```